# Flutter debug local variables: how to show object identifier?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

Flutter debug local variables: how to show object identifier?

```
Variables
  Locals
    > myObjects: List(3 items)
      -[0] MyObject
           wrapped: MyObject
      -[1] MyObject
      -[2] MyObject
```

In java debugger like Intellij, object instance is shown as MyObject@12345

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/describeIdentity.html

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to tell VSC to show object hashCode for debug locals/variables?